# jquery fadeOut() the same element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which notifies the user when something happens:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').fadeOut(9000);
```

It works great the first time, but then, of course, the element is still set to hidden and has the same text.  So when the user triggers it again, nothing happens.  I've tried immediately setting the html() to empty and showing it, but that happens immediately, so you never see the text.  I suppose I could make it "reset" when they open the edit dialog, but I'm sure someone has a simple way around this.

Comment: Whats the code that triggers this? Might be useful in helping to solve your issue.

Comment: It's the success function of an ajax call to a WCF service, which itself is called by a click event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.show()` just before `.fadeOut()`:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').show().fadeOut(9000);
```

To cancel the current animation, use `.stop(true, true)`:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').stop(true, true).show().fadeOut(9000);
```

Comment: Man, I thought that was going to solve BOTH my problems.  It does work, as the other solution, but if you try to trigger the event again before it completely fades, it won't work.  You have to wait until the first one finished.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

there is a callback function you can add as a parameter to fadeOut. It will be called once the animation is completed. Check out the docs, here: [fadeOut Docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

So, try this:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').fadeOut(9000, function(){
    window.parent.$(".Toast").html('')
});
```

Comment: That makes sense... trying now

Comment: inside of the anonymous function you can also just use the $(this) to reference the node being animated (instead of "selecting" it all over again)

Comment: Thanks!! That works, but if it's not complete it won't register the next one (which makes sense).  Any ideas on that?  Should I make it a new question?

Comment: I tried that and actually got an error.  Maybe because I'm dealing with an iFrame?  Not sure.

Comment: ahhh iframe... could be... can you put a jsfiddle up?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show the elements once you change the html:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').show().fadeOut(9000);
```

but, I think that delay has the effect that you are looking for:

```
window.parent.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').fadeIn().delay(9000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with iframe, Can you try the below code? It should solve your problem.

```
window.top.$(".Toast").html('Successfully Did Something!').fadeOut(9000, function(){
    $(this).html('').css("opacity", 1).hide();
});
```